# Polymorph type specification

Tags: coq, lambda-calculus

I've created a type that define (nat,bool) -> T couples:

```
Definition pprod_nb : Set := forall T:Set, (nat -> bool -> T) -> T.
```

Now i want to specialize pprod_nb with T = nat :

```
(nat -> bool -> nat) -> nat
```

My question is : how to specify a type of the form forall T:Set, ... ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot understand the question, please rewrite it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your type `pprod_nb` is too large (it's a function type) to be a `Set`, so you need to make it a `Type` or you'll get a universe inconsistency error:

```
Definition pprod_nb : Type := forall T:Set, (nat -> bool -> T) -> T.
```

If I understand correctly you mean "specialize" and not "specify". The type above can't be specialized since it's a higher-order or rank 2 type (a term you would see in Haskell if you use an appropriate extension, like `Rank2Types`). Instead, it refers to functions that work for all types `T`; since polymorphic functions can't inspect types and behave differently for different types in Coq (the technical term for this is parametric polymorphism), such functions behave uniformly regardless of what result type `T` they produce.

Here's another higher-order type (it's not a type on its own, it's a function that produces a type) that you can specialize:

```
Definition pprod_nb' : Set -> Type := fun T:Set => (nat -> bool -> T) -> T.

Eval compute in (pprod_nb' nat).
(*
     = (nat -> bool -> nat) -> nat
     : Type
*)

(* check that these two definitions are indeed exactly the same *)
Theorem pprod_nb'_is_pprod_nb_forall :
  pprod_nb = forall T, pprod_nb' T.
Proof. reflexivity. Qed.
```

I've written it in a way to highlight similarity to your `pprod_nb` definition, but it would more naturally be written `Definition pprod_nb' T := (nat -> bool -> T) -> T.`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your definition as given isn't accepted by Coq:

```
The term "forall T : Set, (nat -> bool -> T) -> T" has type 
"Type" while it is expected to have type "Set" (universe inconsistency).
```

Are you sure that is the definition you are using?

To answer what I believe is your actual question, I think you want `T` to be a parameter:

```
Definition pprod_nb (T : Set) : Set := (nat -> bool -> T) -> T.
```

This way `pprod_nb` is of type `Set -> Set`, so you can apply it to `nat`:

```
Definition pprod_nb_nat := pprod_nb nat.
```

And this gives the type you seem to want:

```
Eval compute in pprod_nb_nat.
      = (nat -> bool -> nat) -> nat
      : Set
```

Comment: This kind of construction is known as an *impredicative encoding*.  If you want to play this game, it might be interesting to look up the litterature from the early days of Coq (before inductive types were introduced).  Also, adding the `-impredicative-set` flag on the command line when calling `coqtop` or `coqide` might be useful.

Comment: Like Yves said, i am using -impredicative-set as i'm working on polymorphic types. I cannot change my definition because it is the direct traduction of a lambda-term.